# Getting bulk data into a busy table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I am currently performing analysis on a client's MSSQL Server. I've already fixed many issues (unnecessary indexes, index fragmentation, `NEWID()` being used for identities all over the shop etc), but I've come across a specific situation that I haven't seen before.

Process 1 imports data into a staging table, then Process 2 copies the data from the staging table using an `INSERT INTO`. The first process is very quick (it uses `BULK INSERT`), but the second takes around 30 mins to execute. The "problem" SQL in Process 2 is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO ProductionTable(field1,field2)
SELECT field1, field2
FROM SourceHeapTable (nolock)
```

The above INSERT statement inserts hundreds of thousands of records into ProductionTable, each  row allocating a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`, and inserting into about 5 different indexes. I appreciate this process is going to take a long time, so my issue is this: while this import is taking place, a 3rd process is responsible for performing constant lookups on ProductionTable - in addition to inserting an additional record into the table as such:

```
INSERT INTO ProductionTable(fields...)
VALUES(values...)

SELECT *
FROM ProductionTable (nolock)
WHERE ID = @Id
```

For the 30 or so minutes that the `INSERT...SELECT` above is taking place, the `INSERT INTO` times-out.

My immediate thought is that SQL server is locking the entire table during the `INSERT...SELECT`. I did quite a lot of profiling on the server during my analysis, and there are definitely locks being allocated for the duration of the `INSERT...SELECT`, though I fail remember what type they were.

Having never needed to insert records into a table from two sources at the same time - at least during an ETL process - I'm not sure how to approach this. I've been looking up `INSERT` table hints, but most are being made obsolete in future versions.

It looks to me like a `CURSOR` is the only way to go here?

Answer (score 2):

You could consider BULK INSERT for Process-2 to get the data into the ProductionTable.

Another option would be to batch Process-2 into small batches of around 1000 records and use a Table Valued Parameter to do the INSERT. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx#BulkInsert

Comment: I did think about batching it - but with a cursor again.

I didn't think Bulk-insert would be appropriate for a production table... I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like table lock.

Try portion insert in ETL process. Something like

```
while 1=1
begin

   INSERT INTO ProductionTable(field1,field2)
   SELECT top (1000) field1, field2
   FROM SourceHeapTable sht (nolock)
   where not exists (select 1 from ProductionTable pt where pt.id = sht.id)

   -- optional
   --waitfor delay '00:00:01.0'

   if @@rowcount = 0 
      break;

end
```